# Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT returns to previous activity falsely

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a problem with using `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.
In my Andoird App I created a button, which should lead the user to a certain folder and displays the containing pictures. This works so far: The user presses the button -> he can choose between i.e. ES Data Explorer or Galary -> The folder and the containing pictures get displayed.

But there's a problem: When the user touches a picture to enlarge it, the app returns to the previous activity with my button instead of showing this picture.

To open my the folder in my app I am using this code, which gets executed after the user pressed the button:

```
public void openFolder(View View)
{   
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath()
        + "/myfolder");
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select App"));  
}
```

How to fix this unwanted behavior?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When the user touches a picture to enlarge it

Um, no.

> the app returns to the previous activity with my button instead of showing this picture.

Correct. You asked for a third-party application to show an activity that allows the user to choose a picture. The third-party application is showing an activity that allows the user to choose a picture. On a touchscreen device, touching the picture is a very likely way for the third-party app to allow the user to choose a picture.

Or, to put it another way, there is nothing in [the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) that would indicate that third-party apps supporting it should be allowing users to enlarge images.

Furthermore, if you read the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, you will notice that it documents the output. That indicates that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`. The *only* reason to use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is to allow the user to choose something and return that choice to you.

If you want the user to enlarge images, write your own image-enlarging UI. Or, write your own image-browsing UI, and use `ACTION_VIEW` to launch a third-party image viewer for a specific image, as *probably* some of those will allow zoom (though that too is not required).

Comment: ok, thanks for this info.
but I just like to open for example the ES Data Exlorer in a specific folder. Like I would navigate to this folder manually. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @SimonIrsch: You would have to ask the authors of that app.

Comment: I thought there's a way to open the ES File explorer or a similar app with a given repository, but there is no general way.... Thanks for you help anyway!